# Ho do I delete specific strings from every cell of a selected column

Tags: excel, vba

```
                         COLUMN A

       DLBL GPFGBSM,'PHGP.GPFGBSM.GBS.KSDS',,VSAM,CAT=PCAT2                 
       DLBL GPFGGIM,'PHGP.GPFGGIM.GGI.KSDS',,VSAM,CAT=PCAT2                 
36     DLBL GPFEXT1,'PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS',,VSAM,CAT=PCAT3                 
       DLBL FILE01,'PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS',,VSAM,CAT=PCAT3                  
       DLBL FILE1,'PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS',,VSAM,DISP=(NEW,DELETE)
```

I have a spreadsheet which contains many file names inside one single cell under column A (as shown here,there are other file names as well).Now I must write only the part between '             '.for example : I want to replace each cells with only the file name i.e. PHGP.GPFGBSM.GBS.KSDS.Is that possible?

Comment: Have no idea where to begin @simoco

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [help]

Answer (score 0):

Create a column next to this column and use this formula in cell B1.  Then use fill to copy this formula down the column.  Column B will then have the info you want.  If you want to discard the original row, you can then copy and paste (Paste Special - Values) into column A.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("'", A1) + 1, FIND("'", A1, FIND("'", A1) + 1)-FIND("'",A1) - 1)
```

This formula uses the `MID(text, start_num, num_chars)` function to get a substring of the original text.  It uses `FIND(find_text, within_text, [start_num])` to get the index of the first apostrophe and another find that only searches after the first apostrophe for the second index.  It uses the difference between the two indices to know how long the string should be.

Edit:  Based on your new requirements, you will just have to extend the current solution to apply to up to five things in apostrophes.  This is probably a bit complex for excel formulas, VBA might be a better bet.

Comment: Thanks Coda17.But its only showing one file name instead of five.Why is that?

Comment: In your example, is each line it's own cell?  Or is the entirety of your code block one cell?  What I did works for the former.

Comment: Its entirely the code block of a single cell.In this case its cell A1.

Comment: So what do you want the final result to be?  A comma separated list of the things in the apostrophes?  Or do you need a column that will be much longer in length that has each thing in apostrophes in its own cell?

Comment: The final results should be like this:
      PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS
      PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS
 Only each file names in apostrophes one after another in their own cells.Is it doable?

Comment: So you want only the first two things in apostrophes?  Or do you want all of it and just didn't type it.  Additionally, are the number of things that are in apostrophes always the same for each cell?

Comment: The final results should be like this:

  PHGP.GPFGBSM.GBS.KSDS   
  PHGP.GPFGGIM.GGI.KSDS    
  PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS    
  PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS     
  PHGP.GPFPWO4.PWO.ESDS    

Thanks for reaching out :)

Comment: More like one after another all the five file names inside one single cell.